# How to use Virtual scrolling with vuetify timeline

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify timeline component from vuetify framework.

Hi,  I have a sample similar to vuetify timeline sample(https://codepen.io/luizalves/pen/bGoxEvz?editors=101).

My problem is that when there are many items, the dom take a long time to render timeline-items when scrolling down.

How could I use v-virtual-scroll to solve it or somethig as lazy loading?

Code

```html
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-timeline
          align-top
          :dense="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown"
        >
          <v-timeline-item
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="i"
            :color="item.color"
            :icon="item.icon"
            fill-dot
          >
            <v-card
              :color="item.color"
              dark
            >
              <v-card-title class="text-h6">
                Lorem Ipsum Dolor
              </v-card-title>
              <v-card-text class="white text--primary">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no nam oblique veritus. Commune scaevola imperdiet nec ut, sed euismod convenire principes at. Est et nobis iisque percipit, an vim zril disputando voluptatibus, vix an salutandi sententiae.</p>
                <v-btn
                  :color="item.color"
                  class="mx-0"
                  outlined
                >
                  Button
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-timeline-item>
        </v-timeline>
      </v-app>
    </div>
```

```js
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        items: [
          {
            color: 'red lighten-2',
            icon: 'mdi-star',
          },
          {
            color: 'purple darken-1',
            icon: 'mdi-book-variant',
          },
          {
            color: 'green lighten-1',
            icon: 'mdi-airballoon',
          },
          {
            color: 'indigo',
            icon: 'mdi-buffer',
          },
        ],
      }),
    })
```

Comment: @Ferry Kranenburg If it´s a problem for you just doesn't answer the question.  AFAIK, It´s common  all of us to use some code to answer the questions in SO.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg he is infact asking a question instead of getting spoon fed by someone. Why do you think that it is not the case; I am curious.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this? You replace the `v-for` loop and hand it over to the virtual scroll component.

```html
<v-virtual-scroll
      :items="items"
      :item-height="50"
      height="300"
    >
      <template v-slot:default="{ item }">
          <v-timeline-item
            :color="item.color"
            :icon="item.icon"
            fill-dot
          >

....
```

Comment: Thank you. I did. But the problem is my  "item-height" is not fixed. It´s dynamic containing v-cards and  v-card-text with variable content height

Comment: Dynamic heights and virtual scrollers can not really go together. It needs to calculate how large the scrollbar needs to be (how large the area will be if all the items are rendered) when you want to scroll to a particular location, it can calculate how much it needs to scroll. Only possible with fixed heights I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

to solve my problem I put a v-sheet and added a class that enables the scroll.

```
   <v-sheet height="300"> 
          <v-timeline density="compact" class="overflow-y-auto" align="start">
            <v-timeline-item
              v-for="message in messages"
              :key="message.time"
              :dot-color="message.color"
              size="x-small"
            >
              <v-scroll>
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <div class="font-weight-normal">
                    <strong>{{ message.from }}</strong> @{{ message.time }}
                  </div>
                  <div>{{ message.message }}</div>
                </div>
              </v-scroll>
            </v-timeline-item>
          </v-timeline>
        </v-sheet>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
```